# Sliding images in Bootstrap's Carousel next to eachother

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Please take a look at the carousel in [this link](http://bethhaim.spin-demo.com/history).

Is there a way I can alter the code of Twitter Bootstrap's carousel to make the images slide properly instead of messing up like they do now?

Comment: Can you clarify specifically what is wrong currently?

Comment: This website looks really messed up in 16:9 monitors, you should fix that, here I'll start you off: `#primary {background-color: white; height: 473px; width: 1000px; overflow: hidden;}`

Answer (score 1):

Try to add to the outer div containing the carousel with classname 'carousel', the extra classname: 'slide'.

You will get an sliding carousel with this:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <!-- Carousel items -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="active item">…</div>
    <div class="item">…</div>
    <div class="item">…</div>
    </div>
    <!-- Carousel nav -->
    <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
    <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I looked at your code and all of your images are wrapped within a `<div class="item">...</div>` which is correct. However, one of these must be set to `active` so you'd need to make one of them `<div class="item active">`.

Comment: One of them is made active via jQuery code like so: `$('.item:first').addClass('active');`